# Relaciones entre dos clases, y una tercera siendo una clase embeddable

Tags: openxava

Tengo las siguientes Entidades: Compra, Inventario y Medicamento. Compra es
Embbedable e Inventario contiene relación de ManyToOne con Medicamento y tiene como colección a Compra (detalles de compra como num de compra, medicamento, etc) Quiero saber cuáles son las anotaciones para que en compra se pueda agregar más de un medicamento a la vez (mostrando el medicamento como DescriptionsList) y por otra parte, cómo hacer la relación de compra entre estos para que se vea reflejado en estas entidades en el localhost.

**Esta es mi entity Compra: **

````
 ```package com.uam.CLINICA.model;

import java.time.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

import org.openxava.annotations.;
import org.openxava.calculators.;

import lombok.*;

@Embeddable
@Getter @Setter
@View(members = "numCompra, fecha;"
+ "cantidad;" +
"proveedor;"
)

public class Compra{

//@Required
private int numCompra;

@DefaultValueCalculator(CurrentLocalDateCalculator.class)
private LocalDate fecha;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
@DescriptionsList
private Medicamento medicamento;

//@Required
private int cantidad;

@ManyToOne
@DescriptionsList
private Proveedor proveedor;
} ```
````

Mi entity inventario:

````
 ```package com.uam.CLINICA.model;

import java.util.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

import org.openxava.annotations.*;

import lombok.*;

@Entity
@Getter @Setter
@View(name="Simple", members="lote,vencimiento,presentacion,minimoExistencia;"
+ "indicaciones;")

public class Inventario extends Identificable{

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        optional = true)
@DescriptionsList
private Medicamento medicamento;

//@Required
private Date lote;

//@Required
private Date vencimiento;

//@Required
private String presentacion;

@Stereotype("MEMO")
private String indicaciones;

@ElementCollection
// @ListProperties("")
private Collection<compra> compra;</compra>

} ```
````

**y Medicamento: **

````
 ```package com.uam.CLINICA.model;

import java.util.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

import org.openxava.annotations.*;

import lombok.*;

@Entity
@Getter @Setter
@View(name="Simple", members="nombre,nombreGenerico;"
+ "cantidadExistencia;"
+ "detalleMedicamento;")
public class Medicamento extends Identificable {

//@Required
private String nombre;

//@Required
private String nombreGenerico;

//@Required
private Integer cantidadExistencia;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="medicamento", cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
private List<Inventario> inventario;
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Las primeras lecciones del curso te pueden llegar a servir de guia, compra como detalle, medicamento como producto y inventario como factura.
https://openxava.org/OpenXavaDoc/docs/basic-domain-model1_es.html